# Error during module installation due to xml records referring to each other

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

I'm working on odoo module development, left to me by previous programmer. I figured out how most of the code works, but there are some weird parts, that too hard to understand. One example down below: two records (form and action of this form), that referring to each other

```
<!-- temp validation action-->
<record id="model_action_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Password validation</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">scores.temp</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="Scores.my_specific_view"/>
</record>

<!-- temp validation form-->
<record id="my_specific_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">password.form2</field>
    <field name="model">scores.temp</field>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="Scores.model_action_id"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Password Form Validation">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="user_id" />
                    <field name="password" password="True" default_focus="1"/>
                    <button
                        name="validation"
                        type="object"
                        string="Sign"
                        context="{'password':password,'user_id':user_id,}"
                        class="oe_inline oe_stat_button".
                        icon="fa-check-circle-o"
                    />
                    <button 
                        name="cancel"
                        string="Cancel"
                        special="cancel"
                        class="oe_inline oe_stat_button"
                        icon="fa-stop"
                    />
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>
```

When I'm trying to install this module on a new server, it gives error:

```
ParseError: "External ID not found in the system: Scores.my_specific_view"
```

It's searching for **my_specific_view**, but it's obviously not defined yet at this point. Fun part is, it somehow works on the old server, but I don't exactly understand how. It may be caused by first record, that somehow loaded in memory before reference was made, but that's my only theory. I'll try to find a way to contact programmer, who made it, but it may take a while.
Any advices of how to avoid this conflict during installation will be highly appreciated.

upd.

in case, described in 1st answer (changed code below):

```
<!-- temp validation form-->
<record id="my_specific_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">password.form2</field>
    <field name="model">scores.temp</field>
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="Scores.model_action_id"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Password Form Validation">
            <sheet>
                <group>
                    <field name="user_id" />
                    <field name="password" password="True" default_focus="1"/>
                    <button
                        name="validation"
                        type="object"
                        string="Sign"
                        context="{'password':password,'user_id':user_id,}"
                        class="oe_inline oe_stat_button".
                        icon="fa-check-circle-o"
                    />
                    <button 
                        name="cancel"
                        string="Cancel"
                        special="cancel"
                        class="oe_inline oe_stat_button"
                        icon="fa-stop"
                    />
                </group>
            </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<!-- temp validation action--><!--
<record id="model_action_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
            <field name="name">Password validation</field>
            <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
            <field name="res_model">scores.temp</field>
            <field name="view_type">form</field>
            <field name="target">new</field>
            <field name="view_mode">form</field>
            <field name="view_id" ref="Scores.my_specific_view"/>
</record>-->
```

It ends with another errors look like below:

```
ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) `arch` failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Model not found: scores.temp

Error context:
View `password.form2`
```

Same error message even if the action form remains uncommented.

upd2

In addition to what I've described above, model *scores.temp* wasn't found because I renamed it before in my *models.py* file. Now it finally works, problem is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try by defining the view for first, excluding the act_window_id field, then you can define the action.
In the end you can update the view adding that field.

This is what I mean

```
<!-- temp validation form-->
<record id="my_specific_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">password.form2</field>
    <field name="model">scores.temp</field>
<!--        <field name="act_window_id" ref="Scores.model_action_id"/>-->
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <form string="Password Form Validation">
        <sheet>
            <group>
                <field name="user_id" />
                <field name="password" password="True" default_focus="1"/>
                <button
                    name="validation"
                    type="object"
                    string="Sign"
                    context="{'password':password,'user_id':user_id,}"
                    class="oe_inline oe_stat_button".
                    icon="fa-check-circle-o"
                />
                <button 
                    name="cancel"
                    string="Cancel"
                    special="cancel"
                    class="oe_inline oe_stat_button"
                    icon="fa-stop"
                />
            </group>
        </sheet>
        </form>
    </field>
</record>

<!-- temp validation action-->
<record id="model_action_id" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Password validation</field>
        <field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>
        <field name="res_model">scores.temp</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="target">new</field>
        <field name="view_mode">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="Scores.my_specific_view"/>
</record>

<record id="my_specific_view" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="act_window_id" ref="Scores.model_action_id"/>
</record>
```

Comment: I've tried it, it cannot find **scores.temp** in that case.

`ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) 'arch' failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Model not found: scores.temp

Error context:
View 'password.form2'`

Comment: this error seems to me a complete different kind: doesn't find the model itself! could you please send the view part of what you tried? then be sure that the model is defined correctly

Comment: I've added records in it's current state with error message to my question.
Thanks for helping.

Comment: I've added a snippet, what you tried is not what I meant, I suppose there's been a misunderstanding

Comment: Forgot to comment `<field name="act_window_id" ref="Scores.model_action_id"/>` in my question, it was commented actually, but yes, a little misunderstanding. Gonna try your suggestion now, thanks.

Comment: Exactly the same error, it cannot find **scores.temp**.
I've commented `<field name="name">password.form2</field>` and added it below in the same manner as you did, then it started to yell at `<field name="name">password.form2</field>`. After completing the same pattern at `<field name="name">password.form2</field>`, I've got `ParseError: "ValidateError
Field(s) 'arch' failed against a constraint: Invalid view definition

Error details:
Model not found: False

Error context:
View 'None form'`

Comment: are you sure the *__init__.py* of the module is correctly importing the file containing the **scores.temp** model?

Comment: I think so, models are stored in file named **models.py**, **init.py** contains this string: _import models_. Also. it works as it is on the old server, nothing changed.

Comment: I am not able to help you further, without a complete check on the code and on the errors, sorry.

Comment: Today I've returned to that problem and.. shame to admit, but I forgot that I've renamed model temp earlier, so it's all clear now.
So what to do with that question? Should I write an answer about it to let people know or just accept your answer?

Comment: IMHO, if my answer solved the issue but it did not work in the beginning just because of this renaming then accept it, but edit your question in order to inform others that the second error was due to this renaming.